# PendingIntent.send throws exception when old activity no long exists

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have an Activity Class that is calling an IntentService class to do some work

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NetworkHandler.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = createPendingResult(1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
intent.putExtra(NetworkHandler.REFRESH_CONTENT, NetworkHandler.GRO);
intent.putExtra("pendingIntent", pendingIntent);

startService(intent);
```

After the IntentService is done I trigger the call back to the Activity by

```
pendingIntent.send();
```

However, if the user pressed the Back button when IntentService is still running in the background, when pending intent tries to trigger the callback, I get a NullPointException.

What would be the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a private BroadcastReceiver class for this problem.

```
private class RefreshStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private RefreshStatusReceiver() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int requestType = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle").getInt(NetworkHandler.REQUEST_TYPE);

        if (requestType == NetworkHandler.FLY) {
            configHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

and register and unregister them in my onPause and onResume method

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mRefreshStatusReceiver = new RefreshStatusReceiver();
    IntentFilter mStatusIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(NetworkHandler.REFRESH_COMPLETED_ACTION);
    mStatusIntentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRefreshStatusReceiver, mStatusIntentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRefreshStatusReceiver);
}
```

In my IntentService I started the call back as follows

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(CONNECTION_STATE, connectionState);
    bundle.putInt(REQUEST_TYPE, requestType);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(REFRESH_COMPLETED_ACTION).putExtra("bundle",bundle);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
```

I couldn't use the Otto bus class since it only works when both caller and callee are on the main thread (use Eventbus from greenbot if you want different thread). Also the callback is called on a different context, which will not let me make toast from original activity's context ect..

Answer (score 0):

`createPendingResult()`, while easy, does assume that the original `Activity` sticks around -- it's there to support `startActivityForResult()`. I would recommend using some other communications path from the service to the activity, such as:

- `LocalBroadcastManager`
- [Otto](http://square.github.com/otto/)
- `Messenger`